# A form of Vishnu with all Navagrahas

Tags: scripture, vishnu, sri-vaishnava, navagraha, purusha

I know there is a Nakshatrapurusa or form of Vishnu with all Nakshatras, but is there one with all Navagrahas or a Navagrahapursa of sorts?